# Custom Error message for DB errors (Spring).

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Folks, I need some guidance. I'm currently building out an API that returns JSON results to my users. In one use case, I have an endpoint that allows my customer to register a user. I have a table called "Person" with two unique constraints "email" and "username". Normally when this is violated there's an error thrown and the endpoint returns the stack trace. I'm trying to eliminate that by returning custom error messages in JSON format.

I was wondering, is there a way I could create like an Aspect related exception translator that converts these generic errors into something meaningful and less verbose?

I'm using Spring JPA/Hibernate.

Thanks.

Comment: same here . any new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at @ExceptionHandler (per controller) or @ControllerAdvice (global). These will let you handle exceptions thrown by the persistence layer in one place in the view layer and transform them prior to sending the response back to the client. Check [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for a good tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm using this in some respects. My problem with the @ExceptionHandler is that, the handler method gets the error message thrown and essentially I would have to parse it to get the "field" from the table that threw the error. Essentially I would have to do a bunch of parsing. I was wondering if there's another way maybe, like a database translator adapter.